# Вывести имя отправителя и получателя сообщения и текст сообщения из базы данных mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблицы :

- `accounts` с столбцами `accounts.id` и `accounts.name`  - где хранятся все пользователи
- `messages`  с столбцами `recipient_id` и `timeline_id` - где хранятся id отправителя и получателя сообщений.

Как мне сформировать sql запрос так, чтобы он мне вывел :

> **Имя отправителя**, **Имя получателя** (ссылаясь на таблицу accounts) и **Текст сообщения**

Comment: а на чём вы собираетесь выводить, на php?

Comment: нет просто в базе данных

Comment: Во первых по вопросу совершенно не ясно что конкретно надо получить, покажите какой вывод ожидается на основе приведенных входных данных. Во вторых с картинки перебивать данные для теста запроса никто не будет, надо давать данные в текстовом виде. И в третьих, покажите что вы уже сами сделали для решения задачи

Comment: Все  я уже сам разобрался

Comment: @СергейСамохвалов прикрепите свой ответ, чтобы тему можно было закрыть

Comment: уже прикрепил,всем спасибо

Comment: @СергейСамохвалов да ладно, чего тут, незачто )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ, уже сам разобрался :

```
SELECT f.name, accounts.name, messages.text
FROM messages INNER JOIN accounts, accounts AS f
WHERE accounts.id = messages.timeline_id
AND f.id = messages.recipient_id
AND messages.timeline_id = '55'
```